# How to numerically get expectation of a non-linear function of a normally distributed random variable

Tags: expected-value, integral, numerical-integration

I'm trying to calculate the expectation of the following numerically:

$$\mathbb{E}[V(\theta)]$$ where $\theta\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $V(\theta)$ is strictly increasing.

I'm struggling to understand what would be the efficient grid points where there are no upper and lower bounds. If I imagine 1000 uniform grid points in $[-M,M] $ for some finite positive number $M$, then it will be Riemann integral, but I'm losing a lot of points for the extreme values.

Is there a nice by-pass or convention that people do in terms of numerical analysis for this case?

Any help would be tremendously helpful.

Comment: a few questions to start with :-)
1) Is V(.) an analytically known function?
2) Is Monte Carlo integration (i.e. by simulation) out of question?
3) Can $V(\theta)f(\theta)$, where $f$ is the probability density function of $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, be bounded by some "nice" integrable function?

Comment: 1) I want to say V(.) is a known function. 2) I would not want to use MC method, as this is just one part of my value function iteration. I'm already suffering from computational speed. 3) V itself is a bounded function

Comment: 3) sounds good. Do you know the upper bound?
4) do you have access to the cumulative distribution function and the quantile function of the normal distribution? (Or: which language do you use)

Comment: Super thanks. I'm using julia, and there is package to bring cdf and quantile function. I could find some reference having the same problem as mine. Some restrict the domain to mean - 3 standard deviation and mean + 3 standard deviation and use truncated normal distribution.

Comment: Do you have particular reasons not to use numerical integration packages? Julia has QuadGK, https://juliamath.github.io/QuadGK.jl/stable/, that can calculate integrals from $-\infty$  to $+\infty$, to the best possible accuracy. If you replace $I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} V(\theta)f(\theta)d\theta$ by the integral on $[-M,+M]$, you might miss out the part where $V(\theta)$ takes large values.